# JPA/Hibernate CollectionOfElements in Scala

Tags: hibernate, scala, collections

In Scala, if I define a simple `@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements`, it does not work.

And somehow I cannot specify something like `@CollectionOfElements(targetElement = xyz.class)` in scala. It vomits on typing ".class".

Anyone know how I can get any of the `CollectionOfElements` family of annotations to work in scala? I just want something simple like the following to work:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements (targetElement = Long.class)
var updatedQuestions : java.util.List[Long] = _
```

BTW I posted this on [How to create custom query for CollectionOfElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069518/how-to-create-custom-query-for-collectionofelements/10484359#10484359), but realized that that probably was not a Scala related thread. **My issue is specific to using this in Scala**. I dont have any issue in using this in standard Java.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements (targetElement = classOf[Long])
```